# Can't remember book title: a journalist converses with a death row convict

Tags: identification-request

I'm searching for the title of a book, my memories are quite hazy, very vague, as I read it a few years back. The plot goes something like this: a journalist converses with a death row convict, and eventually, an exchange takes place (I can't recall the details) where the journalist takes the place of the inmate (who manages to escape) and is executed in their stead.

Comment: You're not thinking of [the same story as this previous question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/21698/17)?